# Collected works of Mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, reference-works

The collected work of any mathematician is, in my opinion, more than *collection of his works*. Since it is edited (collected) by some people which have passed through many papers of the mathematician, the *collected work* contains important summary about the work of the mathematician. For example, consider the famous "Feit-Thomson theorem"-groups of odd order are solvable. This was actually conjectured by Burnside with so-much work; he proved it for groups of (odd) order up to 40,000. This I found in the *Collected work of William Burnside* (see [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=MOO2rEEBMaEC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=collected%20work%20of%20William%20Burnside&source=bl&ots=O5lW54qMUv&sig=YBPm0LT25tb9jsnv5b83TcJ9qIA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv9eaUqsXMAhWDVY4KHWcDAo8Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=collected%20work%20of%20William%20Burnside&f=false), first two para on page 4).

The collected work that I was searching for was of Group Theorists. I found only two: Philip Hall and William Burnside. In the google - search for collected works, I was getting collected works of non-mathematicians, by mismatching the names of mathematicians.

It would be better if any one can inform about those mathematicians (Group Theorists) whose collected work has been published.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go to two or three libraries known to be very complete regarding mathematics collections (University of Illinois and University of Michigan are two that come to mind) and go through their on-line catalogs for call numbers where collected works are held (I looked up "Peano, G" just now, and it appears QA3 is where most of the collected works are shelved). [Here is a link](http://tinyurl.com/j4az73w) for the appropriate search in a university library near where I live. You'll sometimes have to skip through the series collections also shelved in the QA3 area, by the way.

*(ADDED 3 DAYS LATER)* Since I wrote the above, I was at the library near where I live to look up some books, and I used the opportunity to glance at the shelves where the collected works volumes appear and I noticed that some of the collected works volumes were shelved as far as QA37. So if you do what I suggested, don't stop when you're finished looking through the QA3 books -- keep going at least through the QA37 books.